# How do i detect CMD + Click of a SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do i detect CMD + Click of a SwiftUI view? (MacOS app)

There isnt much detail I can add to this question. Googling has not helped and I have no clue where to begin.

I want that when a user keeps their hand on CMD and then clicks the view, I will run a funciton.
Has anyone a solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following way.

```
 .gesture(TapGesture().modifiers(.command).onEnded{print("Here we are!") })
```